# Pycharm cube selection

Tags: pycharm

somehow I enabled weird selection mode in Pycharm, instead of selecting line by line a select box in editor and I don`t know how to disable it.
[image: Issue image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nah I found the answer, its called **Column Selection Mode** in edit menu tab.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).